# Lexically-scoped ordering behavior

Tags: c++, scope, operator-overloading

I have a class with two definitions of ordering.  (In the real problem, one is a total order and one is a semiorder.)  But it's nice to be able to use the comparison operators rather than always having to use an explicit comparison function or functor object.  So I figured I'd provide some comparison operators like this:

```
class C;

namespace Order1 {
  bool operator< (const C&, const C&);
}
namespace Order2 {
  bool operator< (const C&, const C&);
}
```

Operators for `>`, `<=`, `>=` are also defined of course, but that's not the point.  Now a user can say `using namespace Order1;` or ... `Order2` at file scope or block scope and get the requested behavior for the rest of that file/block.

The disappointing part, which I'd like to improve if possible, is that these `using`s can't nest.

```
void g(const C&, const C&);

using namespace Order1; // for most functions in this file

void f(const C& x, const C& y) {
  bool test1 = x < y; // Order1
  {
    // Would like to switch to Order2 for this block.
    using namespace Order2;
    bool test2 = x < y; // Ambiguous overload!

    g(x, y); // Unaffected by local using-s.
  }
}
```

Since `using`-directives don't hide anything when used in the same namespace, this doesn't provide a way to nicely temporarily reverse the meaning of the operators for a block scope.

Another related idea would be to allow dummy objects on the stack whose constructors and destructors manipulate the "current setting" for which behavior to use.  But I don't think I want to head that way for this situation, since that would mean the equivalent of `f` above could change the behavior of other functions called like `g`.

Is there another way to get a similar effect but allowing nested operations with the innermost block "hiding" the others?  Or am I stuck with one behavior of overloaded operators per declarative region?  Which I guess is manageable, since code can still explicitly use a function or functor instead of using the operators.

Comment: Explicit is good, implicit is bad. Roughly. IMHO. :-)  Cheers,

Comment: One thing I didn't mention is that this is a change to an existing class which already had these operators and is used by thousands of files.  So I'm stuck with providing a "default" operator behavior which is mostly like the old behavior.  But I think I'm going to recommend new code use explicit function or functor instead of messing with the operators at all.  I just hope some coworkers take the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stick with ordinary comparison functions.  The rest of the code will be cleaner.  No `using namespace...` or explicit calls to scoped `operator<`.  Reads easier this way, IMO...

```
int main() {
   bool b = compare1(4, 5);
   b = compare2(4, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using namespace Order2 put in

```
bool test2 = Order2::operator<(x, y);
```

which will work in this instance. If you want to "meta-program", i.e. be able to pass in Order1 / Order2 as a template parameter you should make them structs (or classes) with operator< static. then you can do T::operator<(x, y) where T is either Order1 or Order2.

Comment: If it's going to require a more specific syntax, I'd rather just go with `Order2::compare(x,y) < 0`, or the functor `Order2::Comp()` which inherits `std::binary_function<C,C,bool>`.  I guess I was just trying to be too lazy for my own good.

Comment: If you use a class you can overload operator(). You need to create a "dummy" instance of the class. Then you use compareObj(x,y).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you scrap the namespaces, and just declare two overloads of `operator <` with different argument types, one for each class type?

**UPDATE**

As dgnorton has pointed out in a comment below, you have one class, with two different orderings defined on it.  This does seem like a possible cause of problems.  Is it possible to split this into two different classes?

Comment: In his case the class type is the same...he wants different behavior for the same operator...which probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: It may be a good idea if he is going to pass the predicate into an algorithm or a a std::set or similar to give different ordering. If he puts the maps into each namespace it might pick up the operator from that namespace automatically, although Koenig Lookup suggests it might look to the namespace of the class itself first.